# Change Pin's color in MapKit - Swift 4 - Xcode 10 - iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I am trying to change the color of the pin used in my map in MapKit in Xcode. I found this in the Apple Developer Documentation:

Declaration (iOS, tvOS):

```
var pinTintColor: UIColor! { get set }
```

I am new to code and I can't figure out what I should put in get and set, could you please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: You should add a little context around your code, it will help users to help you :-)

Comment: Cant you just use 'yourPin.pinTintColor = .red' for example?

Comment: No this technique is not valid anymore unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView?.pinTintColor = .purple

    }
    else {
        pinView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    return pinView
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it is not working for me, I might do something wrong though.